# How to write overlay-specification–aware macros that work w/o the beamer class

Tags: beamer, macros, best-practices, package-writing, beamerarticle

The LaTeX `beamer` class provides with `\newcommand<>` and `\newenvironment<>` an interface to define own commands that can deal with beamer's overlay specifications. Internally, commands defined this way then typically employ other beamer-provided overlay-aware commands, such as `\only<>` or  `\onslide<>`, to achieve the desired effect.

**However, how does one write a package that provides its commands overlay-aware if used together with `beamer`, but can also be used with other document classes?**

The brute force solution would be to define every command twice, depending of it being used within beamer or not:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
  % beamer
  \newcommand<>{\foo}[1]{\only#2{...}}
  \newcommand<>{\bar}[1]{... \onslide#2{...}}
}{%
  % other class
  \newcommand{\foo}[1]{...}
  \newcommand{\bar}[1]{...}
}
```

However, I would prefer an approach that just mimics a beamer-like interface, so that the actual macro definitions can be kept as is:

```
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
  % beamer ==> do nothing
}{%
  % other class ==> provide beamer command mockups
  \def\newcommand ...
  \def\onslide ...
  \def\only ...
}

\newcommand<>{\foo}[1]{\only#2{...}}
\newcommand<>{\bar}[1]{... \onslide#2{...}}
```

There is the `beamerarticle` package that is intended to provide these commands for beamer's article mode (used in the MWE below). However, `beamerarticle` goes way to far, as it also defines commands, such as `\frame` and `\note` and patches, as `beamer` does, basically all of the standard commands for sectioning and lists, which renders it incomapatible to many other packages and document classes. I am looking for a more light-weight, less invasive solution.

I also tried to load the `beamerbaseoverlay` sub-package alone, which apparently provides the definitions of `\newcommand<>`, `\only<>` and so on. However, this package is not intended to be used alone; I tried to hunt down its dependencies, but gave it up after loading half a dozen of extra packages without success.

Any other ideas? Any package I did overlook?

MWE with some real code from the package I am currently writing to play around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

% BEGIN package content
\makeatletter

  \@ifclassloaded{beamer}{}{
    \RequirePackage{beamerarticle} % <-- I would like to avoid this!
  }  
  \RequirePackage{tikz}

  % uses beamer's \only<> 
  \tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
  }}

  % uses beamer's \newenvironment<>, onlyenv
  \newenvironment<>{btHighlight}[1][]
  {\begin{onlyenv}#2\begingroup\tikzset{bt@Highlight@par/.style={#1}}\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
  {\end{lrbox}\bt@HL@box[bt@Highlight@par]{\@tempboxa}\endgroup\end{onlyenv}}

  % uses beamer's \newcommand<>, \only<>
  \newcommand<>\btHL[1][]{%
    \only#2{\begin{btHighlight}[#1]\bgroup\aftergroup\bt@HL@endenv}%
  }
  \def\bt@HL@endenv{%
    \end{btHighlight}%   
    \egroup
  }
  \newcommand{\bt@HL@box}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{\wd #2}{\ht #2}}%
      \pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
      \node[anchor=base west,  fill=orange!30,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=1pt, inner ysep=0pt, rounded corners=3pt, minimum height=\ht\strutbox+1pt,#1]{\raisebox{1pt}{\strut}\strut\usebox{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\makeatother
% END package content

\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}[%
      language=C, numbers=left, gobble=4,
      moredelim={**[is][{\btHL[pin=30:The applications entry point, onslide=<2->{fill=red!50}]}]{@}{@}}%
    ]
    @int main (void)@ { 
      printf("Hello World!"); return 0;
    } 
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

According to the beamer manual, a command declared with `\newcommand<>` has access to an extra argument containing the overlay specification; thus, as a general principle, it is not possible to write an overlay-aware command that also functions without change without beamer.

However, one can go the other way, and beamer provides a ready-made way of doing this:

```
\newcommand\foo[2][]{...}
\renewcommand<>\foo[2][]{...\beameroriginal\foo...}
```

Inside the renewed `\foo`, you can use `\beameroriginal\foo` to call on the original definition, even to the extent of adding overlay-aware commands that build on it.  Put that inside an `\@ifclassloaded` and you're good to go.

It would be really convenient if `\renewcommand` itself had this feature.  But the fact that it doesn't means that the analogy

`\renewcommand<>`:`\newcommand<>`::`\renewcommand`:`\newcommand`

fails; it is not the "overlay aware" version of `\renewcommand`, and it is not intended for renewing commands created with `\newcommand<>`; instead, it is intended for renewing commands created with `\newcommand` to behave *as though* they were created with `\newcommand<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `\beameroriginal`, quite handy! However, the approach does not work, if  the overlay-specific part needs to be applied in the middle of the original command, for instance, if the beamer-version should result in `\newcommand<>\foo[1]{\fbox{\only#2{\bfseries}#1}}}`

Comment: @Daniel: I tried for some time to figure out a nice way of doing this and couldn't.  My best idea is to place a "style" macro `\foostyle` at the spot where `\only#2{\bfseries}` would go, and then use `\renewcommand<>` (respectively, `\renewcommand`) to prepend either `\def\foostyle{\only##2{\bfseries}}` or `\def\foostyle{\bfseries}`.  Unfortunately, I can't think of a way of uniformly setting the style.

Comment: @Daniel: To correct that last comment, you can't use `\renewcommand` to add the style, but you can use `\pretocmd` from the `etoolbox` package.  Very handy.