# Patch \include to be overlay aware

Tags: beamer, overlays, include

Is it possible to patch `\include` to be overlay aware?

I tried [known approaches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60683/how-to-write-overlay-specification-aware-macros-that-work-w-o-the-beamer-class/60740#60740) without success.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand<>{\includex}[1]{\only#2{\include{#1}}}                   % works
%\renewcommand<>{\include}[1]{\only#2{\beamerorginal{\include}{#1}}}  % does not work

\begin{document}

\include{testframe}
\only<handout:0>{\include{testframe}}   % works 
\includex<handout:0>{testframe}         % works
%\include<handout:0>{testframe}         % does not work

\end{document}
```

The test frame is simply:

```
\begin{frame}testframe\end{frame}
```

Comment: why do you want to use `\include` here (which implies a new page) rather than simply `\input` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I heavily use `\includeonly` and `\excludeonly`, to include or exclude frames and framesets and also a lot of hyperrefs.

Comment: probably something is possible but it would be more natural to use the `<>` within the file in that case.  `\foo<2>` means put stuff in layer 2 _in this frame_  but `\include{foo}` is `\clearpage stuff \clearpage` so  `<>` seems the wrong level. that said you could obviously define`\include` to look for a `<` and if it sees one do `\only<#1>{\originalinclude{#2}}` for `\include<#1>{#2}`if that's what you need?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, the latter `\include<#1>{#2}` is my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\originalinclude\include

\renewcommand<>{\include}[1]{\only#2{\originalinclude{#1}}}  % does not work

\begin{document}

\include{testframe}
\only<handout:0>{\include{testframe}}   % works 
\include<handout:0>{testframe}         % 

\end{document}
```